# pass value to next page

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I have a php page (search.php) which has a link to another php page. (reserve.php). I want to

```
  1. pass the link text to the next page
  2. display that link text in a input box
```

Please tell me how should I write the proper coding for the above tasks.

search.php

```
<a href="Reserve.php"><?php echo $row['AccNo'];?></a>
```

Comment: You could add the text as a get param and use that on the new page. `<a href="Reserve.php?accno=<?= $row['AccNo'] ?>"><?= $row['AccNo'] ?></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Search.php have

`<a href="Reserve.php?AccNo=<?php echo $row['AccNo']; ?>">Go to Reserve Page</a>`

Now On Reserve.php 
Get that AccNo using `GET`

`$AccNo=$_GET['AccNo'];`

and then just echo the `$AccNo` Variable in your Input Text field

`<input type="text" value="<?php echo $AccNo; ?>" >`

Hope this helps

Comment: If need more help will love to help :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_GET` to accomplish that:

```
<a href="Reserve.php?accno=<?php echo $row['AccNo']?>"><?php echo $row['AccNo'];?></a>
```

In the new page, the variable value is in the variable `$_GET['accno']`. To display that text in an input box, simply use `echo $_GET['accno']`.

Note though that the text will appear in the URL and hence can be altered easily. Depending on the purpose you're using this for, you might want to introduce additional checks, etc. in the new page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `$_SESSION` to pass value through pages.

```
$_SESSION['AccNo'] = $row['AccNo']
```

You can then access it via `$_SESSION['AccNo']` in your other page. Be careful, make sure you started a session using `session_start()` before use session.

If you prefer using something else, @Max answer was also a pretty way to get data from one page to another, but I would not recommend it for sensitive information.